# Using custom helpers in view without full path - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method that truncates a string.

```
StringHelper::truncate()
```

When I use this method in my view it can't find the class StringHelper. I have added it to composer.json and done an dump-autoload.

It works when I specify the full path:

```
\App\Http\Helpers\StringHelper
```

But I'd like to have the first option.

How can I do this? AppServiceProvider maybe, but how?

Comment: Please specify laravel version although you want to search for "alias", "facade".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Right way for Laravel 5.1**

1. Create a [Blade directive](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade) in `AppServiceProvider` class:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('truncate', function ($expression) {
            return "<?php echo trim({$expression}); ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

2. Use it in view like this:

```blade
@truncate($string)
```

Comment: Thank you, already a lot nicer. Still think it's a bit smelly if you use helpers. Still need to provide full path inside the string with backslashes like: return "<?php echo \App\Http\Helpers\StringHelper::truncate($expression); ?>";

Comment: @TimvanUum you don't need to provide full path if you edit the composer.json as I suggested

Comment: @KristofM Thank you for your reply, but I still have to. I have added the file in composer.json. Also have said that in my question. In composer.json you have to add full path to file not the namespace (I have tried the namespace, but then I got the error, file not found). In code I have to give the full namespace. I need to add the namespace to the view or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for Laravel 5**

Add the helper file to the "files" part of your composer.json (in the root of your application) and you won't need to supply the full path every time:

```
"files": [
        "App/Http/Helpers/StringHelper.php"
      ],
```